# How to move mediawiki 'Echo' extension icons?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

so I'm a bit stuck. I have my own private mediawiki and until now I could find everything by myself out. There is an extension called 'Echo' and I find it pretty useful. I don't want to have the extension icons in the 'mw-head -> p-personal' section. I want to move it to my own customized navigation bar. But I don't know how, it looks like it is designed to only work with the stock skin. Maybe someone here can help and has some experience with that extension.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use the [PersonalUrls](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/PersonalUrls) hook. Register it so that it runs after Echo (e.g. via `Hooks::register` which is always called later than the normal hook registration mechanism), remove the `notifications-alert` and `notifications-notice` elements of the array, and render them on your own toolbar.